# Search on chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, google-chrome-extension

Google chrome extension:

I created a **Google chrome extension** and published it on Google Chrome Store,
but I can't find it while searching on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple steps you can try to diagnose the issue

1. Try to refine search by extensions.
2. Try searching your google username.

If neither of these work your extension may not be public and published to everyone (not just testers). Please refer to this guide on how to publish your extension to the world.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#world

Answer (score 0):

An issue I had was that I had uploaded the .zip but never hit publish. Make sure in your developer dashboard it doesn't say draft version where it should say published version.